# Is monitor suspending supported via a HDMI to DVI cable?

Tags: video, hdmi, dvi, adapter, standby

My computer has DVI and HDMI video outputs while I have two DVI monitors and a cheap HDMI to DVI cable.  Both monitors go fine into and out of standby using DVI-to-DVI connection.  Both also display fine via the HDMI-to-DVI connection but won't go into standby like they do with the DVI-to-DVI connection when the computer sleeps or is shut down.  Instead the display behaves like they are not connected and display the "No DVI-D cable" message.

Do I just have a cheap faulty HDMI-to-DVI cable or are the standby signaling technologies between the two different?

I've searched Google but didn't find any definitive answer.

Comment: Have you tried Googling 'monitor won't sleep HDMI-to-DVI cable'? I did and it looks like others have experienced similar issues and Google probably has the answer at its fingertips.

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry for not mentioning this.  Nothing I found gave an answer though.

Comment: BTW, the recursion caused a stack overflow. LOL

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's cable dependent.  I have purchased a different (and still cheap) HDMI-to-DVI cable that suspends and wakes the monitor fine.

It would still be nice to know what pin(s) / signals are used for the power save mode of the monitor.